# Query string containing Chinese characters wrongly interpreted by curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, google-translate, url-encoding

Fixed.  Thanks Jack for the awesome solution.  Please check out the front-end www.papertiger.net.nz/flashcard/

The code is meant to fetch the mp3 of a single Chinese character from translate.google.com.  I'm using the script to get around the google cross domain policy.  I've tried urlencode, rawurlencode, utf8_encode,a combination of utf8_encode and urlencode as well as curl_escape, which it doesn't look like the installation of php on my server has.

Here's the code:

```
 <?php
$q=$_GET['url'];
 header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
 $curl=curl_init();
 $q= utf8_encode($q);$filename=utf8_encode("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh_CN&q=");
 $filename=$filename.urlencode($q);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $filename);
 $voice = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 echo $voice;
?>
```

You can listen to the result [here](http://www.papertiger.net.nz/flashcard/gLoad.php?url=%E4%B8%89).  It should sound closer to "sun".  As you can see [here](http://www.papertiger.net.nz/flashcard/gLoad2.php?url=%E4%B8%89) though, if I have the php echo $filestring instead of $voice, the link is correctly formatted and works fine.  Simple redirects also give the same result, but don't work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but apparently Google checks the user agent; the following works fine on my machine:

```
$url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?' . http_build_query(array(
    'tl' => 'zh_CN',
    'q' => $_GET['url'],
));

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36',
));

header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
curl_exec($ch);
```

The resulting audio produces "san1" for the example you've given.

Comment: replaced my code with the code you suggested.  It's still saying "A" as seen here http://www.papertiger.net.nz/flashcard/gLoad.php?url=%E4%B8%89 .  I have a feeling its something to do with my webhost, but I have no idea what to ask them to look for/fix

Comment: @urbanvintner No worries，加油！:)